# Listar dados em colunas separadas

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap

Tenho a seguinte lista vindo do banco de dados

```
<ul class="list-marked">
    <?php foreach($cidades_presentes as $valor){ ?>
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $valor->categoria; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>                  
</ul>
```

`$cidades_presentes` retorna 15 cidades no seguinte formato:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [id_cidadesbairros] => 0
            [categoria] => Foz do Iguaçu
            [ativo] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [id_cidadesbairros] => 0
            [categoria] => São Miguel do Iguaçu
            [ativo] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [id_cidadesbairros] => 0
            [categoria] => Medianeira
            [ativo] => 1
        )

)
```

A minha questão é: Se retornar 15 linhas, preciso exibir da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
8 itens da lista aqui
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
7 itens da lista aqui
</div>
```

Como eu posso fazer isto?

Atualização,
Função que busca as cidades:

```
public function get_cidades_presentes(){
    $this->db->where("id_cidadesbairros", '0');
    return $this->db->get('cidadesbairros')->result();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um jeito simples de dividir um `array` em blocos iguais (dentro do possível) é usando a função `array_chunk`

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php

Para dividir sua lista de cidades em duas colunas, e exibir em seguida, essa seria uma alternativa bem simples:

```
$colunas = 2;
$linhas  = round(count($cidades) / $colunas, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
$blocos  = array_chunk($cidades, $linhas);
```

Para exibir conforme a pergunta, um bloco por vez:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $colunas; ++$i ) {
   echo '<div class="col-md-3">';
   foreach( $blocos[$i] as $bloco ) {
      echo '<tagDesejada>'.$bloco['categoria'].'</tagDesejada>';
   }
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/H8Y1Ea)**.

(no caso de objetos, como você já notou, seria `$bloco->categoria`)

Se fosse exibir lado a lado, numa tabela:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $linhas; ++$i ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$blocos[0][$i]['categoria'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$blocos[1][$i]['categoria'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hi7F3g)**.

(neste último caso, seria bom um `if` na última coluna para identificar o final do bloco, visto que nem sempre ela vai ter todas as linhas)

Comment: Ok beleza, muito obrigado!